# Fastest way to create a numpy array from a list of `NamedTuple`s?

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to create a `float` `numpy` array from `Point(NamedTuple)`[s] objects (a single object or a list of objects).
It seems that it is x5-8 slower than creating it from a list/tuple of `tuple`s, but as a commenter suggested there are faster ways to do so, of which, the fastest way is ~24% slower than creating an array from a list/tuple of tuples (all options, from fastest to slowest in the snippet below).

```
from typing import NamedTuple

import numpy as np


class Point(NamedTuple):
    lng: float
    lat: float


t = (1, 2)
p = Point(1.0, 2.0)

point_count = 100

lt = [[t] * point_count]
tt = tuple([t] * point_count)
pp = [p] * point_count

print(np.array([tuple(p) for p in pp]).dtype)  # dtype=float. from list of tuples
print(np.array((tuple(p) for p in pp)).dtype)  # dtype=object. from generator - not good
```

```
%timeit -r 4 -n 10_000 np.array(lt, dtype=float)
%timeit -r 4 -n 10_000 np.array(tt, dtype=float)
%timeit -r 4 -n 10_000 np.array([(p[0], p[1]) for p in pp], dtype=float)
%timeit -r 4 -n 10_000 np.array([tuple(p) for p in pp], dtype=float)
%timeit -r 4 -n 10_000 np.array(tuple((p[0], p[1]) for p in pp), dtype=float)
%timeit -r 4 -n 10_000 np.array(tuple((tuple(p) for p in pp)), dtype=float)
%timeit -r 4 -n 10_000 np.array(pp, dtype=float)
```

```
20.2 µs ± 208 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 4 runs, 10,000 loops each)
20.3 µs ± 769 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 4 runs, 10,000 loops each)
25.1 µs ± 261 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 4 runs, 10,000 loops each)
25.4 µs ± 770 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 4 runs, 10,000 loops each)
25.3 µs ± 714 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 4 runs, 10,000 loops each)
27.4 µs ± 646 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 4 runs, 10,000 loops each)
155 µs ± 431 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 4 runs, 10,000 loops each)
```

I've tried to add a `__array__` method to `Point` but it makes it even slower

```
    def __array__(self, dtype=None):
        return np.array((self[0], self[1]))
```

Comment: I tried a few approaches, such as using Numba, or `np.fromiter()`, and it was slower than the solutions you've already found.